# Как найти количество строк длины N,что не содержат S как подстроку?

Tags: c++, python, алгоритм, строки

Дано строку что может содержать только буквы *A,B,C*, тогда количество всех строк длины **N** из етих букв будет ***3^N***,тогда ответ на задачу : ***3^N - (количество строк что имеют подстрочку S)***. *Как эффективно посчитать количество строк что не содержат подстроки S?* А да забыл сказать S содержит только буквы *A,B.*

Ограничения:

```
N = 16
1 <= |S| <= 16
```

Примерчик:

```
2
AB
```

Ответ:

```
8
```

Нам не подходит одна строка AB, тогда количество 3^2 - 1 = 8.Так же написал brute force алгоритм на котором можно проверить тестики:

```
from itertools import product
n = int(input())
s = str(input())
a = [''.join(i) for i in product('ABC',repeat = n) if s not in "".join(i)]
print(len(a))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть `PS[]` - префиксы строки `S` длиной от `1` до `lenS-1`

`F[k][j]` - количество хороших строк длиной `k`, оканчивающихся на `PS[j]`  (в том числе `F[k][0]`, не оканчивающиеся на префиксы)

Похоже, что таблицу `F[][]` заполнить нетрудно ряд за рядом.

Comment: оканчивающихся на PS[j] (в том числе F[k][0], не оканчивающиеся на префиксы  -  я не понимаю что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Строка "ВАСЯ" имеет префиксы "В", "ВА", "ВАС". Хорошая строка "КВАС" заканчивается префиксом длиной 3 и входит в `F[4][3]`, а строка "ПЕТЯ" входит в `F[4][0]`, т.к. не заканчивается ни на один префикс.

Comment: MBo а можно пожалуйста для наглядности пример заполнения,так как хотелось поглубже копнуть подход,а динамическое программирование я только учу...

Comment: Начните с задачи попроще - сколько существует битовых последовательностей длиной N, не содержащих две единицы подряд?

Comment: Откуда такое соотношение?

Comment: Выводил формулку

Comment: Постойте ето не верно,вроде ето количество будёт равно числу фиббоначчи,только на 2 больше,тобеш a[i] = fib(i+2)

Comment: Верно, с числом Фиб. связано. А какая логика связи количества  k-й длины с предыдущими?

Comment: Что оно есть суммой двух предыдущих...

Comment: Я веду к подходу, который может быть использован и в задаче этой темы. Для длины k есть Z(k) хороших последовательностей, кончающихся на 0, и D(k) хороших последовательностей, кончающихся на 1. К первым можно добавить и 0, и 1, а ко вторым только 0. Получается Z(k+1)=Z(k)+D(k),а D(k+1)=Z(k)